# Compile mongodb 3.4.10 with an alternative linker

Tags: mongodb, scons

I am trying to compile mongodb 3.4.10 on SLED11, but it fails on linking problems. I am confident it is caused by the outdated /usr/bin/ld that is used for linking by the scons build system.

I have searched through SConstruct and there is nothing to set which linker is called. I have seen many environment variables controlling compiler flags, linker search paths, linker flags etc but there is nothing for choosing the linker itself.

I believe my gcc toolchain is also correct, I have built a custom gcc to use the alternative linker:

```
$ gcc -print-prog-name=ld
/correct/path/to/alternative/ld
```

I would expect /correct/path/to/alternative/ld to be called, but it is obvious from the logs that still /usr/bin/ld is used.

Is there a way to force scons to use the other linker? I am using scons 2.3.4.

Comment: Consider first using the scons version shipping with the mongodb src in src/third_party/scons-2.5.0/scons.py.    Is SCons explicitly calling /usr/bin/ld, or calling gcc which is then calling /usr/bin/ld?  Can you paste a link command line from your build?

Comment: Well, we invoke the compiler to do the linking for us, I'd be surprised if we ever invoke ld directly, which is why we don't offer a way to select it. I suspect a toolchain issue.